# Java and android XML serializer

Tags: java, android, xml

Is there some SAX serializer similar to Android's XmlSeializer that can be used both in Java and Android? I have to use one library in Java project and in Android project, and I need some way to serialize XML from it. I use SAX serializing so tools like dom4j don't fit (as I can understand).

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I recommend the [XMLPullParser](http://www.xmlpull.org/)

You can use it to parse and serialize XML.  I find it to be faster too.

Here is the [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) for it.

[Serializer doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory.html#serializerClasses)

Comment: I just added a link to the serialization doc.  I use it all the time for serialization and parsing.  I know it works for both Java and Android.  Very slick and Google's preferred XML library.

Answer (score 0):

[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) is reputed to work on Android and I know it works in Java. Example:

```
@XStreamAlias("blah")
class Foo {
   @XStreamAsAttribute
   public String baz = "Stack";
}
```

Now:

```
XStream xstreamInstance = new XStream();
xstreamInstance.processAnnotations(Foo.class);
System.err.println(xstreamInstance.toXML(new Foo());
```

will print out...

```
 <blah baz="Stack"/>
```

Comment: As I see, it serializes objects. And I need to serialize text (like "<sometag someparm="123">sometext</sometag>") without creating a SomeTag class for it.

Comment: You should be able to do that using Annotations, give me 5 minutes or so and I'll be happy to find some code to demonstrate it.

Comment: XMLPullParser is exactly what I needed, because I have nested tags that cannot be encapsulated to objects (or they can, but the objects will be large and scary). So I just need to write them at runtime without knowing the full structure.